# Sharepoint custom list limit number of choices

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list, custom

I've created a custom list in my SharePoint to allow users select a table reservation for our Christmas dinner.

My columns are just; "Name" and "Table Choice", "Table Choice" field has 16 different tables to select.

But 1 table can only have 10 person max so I'd like to Show a warning message if a user tries to reserve an already filled table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd fan out the seats, one seat to every list item, like "Table 1 Seat 1", "Table 1 Seat 2". Then you can have people assign themselves to another column, "Assigned To", or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple ways to handle this scenario.

1. Setup a workflow to handle when the a table is full to remove it from the options table.
2. Use some jQuery and add it to the new and edit forms to check if a table is full when they select a value. Then you could display a message.

Answer (score 0):

Idea based on Mike’s suggestion. You can use “enforce unique values” feature to prevent users from duplicating data.

1. Create a “Seat Choice” column for 10 seats.
2. Create a text column named “Your Seat”.
3. Using JavaScript to set seat (“Table Choice” value and “Seat Choice” value) to “Your Seat” and make it read-only. Or, using InfoPath form to set the default value.

[image]

4. Enforce “Your Seat” on unique values. The “enforce unique values” feature prevents users from duplicating data.

[image]

When user is trying to create duplicate data (the Table-Seat has already be selected), the error message will display and the item cannot be created successfully.